# Pegar arquivos na unidade C:

Tags: java

Utilizando o código:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\email\\email.properties"
```

ele pega a partir do usuário

```
(C:\USUARIO\user\Documents\Netbeans\Projeto\email\email.properties)
```

mas e se estiver na unidade `C:\` somente?

```
 (C:\Email\email\email.properties)
```

Como faço para o `System.getProperty` obter onde quer que esteja?

Comment: return new File(MinhaClasse.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar o caminho da pasta onde o .jar está sendo executado você deve usar o seguinte código, trocando `MinhaClasse` pelo nome da classe atual:

```
MinhaClasse
  .class
  .getProtectionDomain()
  .getCodeSource()
  .getLocation()
  .getPath()
  .getParent() + "\\email\\email.properties";
```

Comment: beleza, estamos no caminho rs. É que a partir da pasta local do arquivo jar pegar outro arquivo do tipo properties. c:\projeto\pasta\file.properties. Estou tentando aqui. E o jar está no C:\projeto\projeto.jar

Comment: É só vc concatenar o caminho da pasta... Daqui poucos minutos edito minha resposta com isso

Comment: No projeto está ficando assim:  /D:/Documentos/NetBeansProjects/EnviarEmail/build/classes/
na unidade C: está ficando c:\projeto\projeto.jar

Comment: consegui resolver. Na verdade era apenas eu que estava tentando executar a partir do usuário errado. No cmd eu dei os comandos cd .. até chegar no C:\projeto e então dei o java -jar projeto e finalmente deu certo. Meu objeto era dar o comando java -jar de qualquer lugar e ele reconhecer o local

Comment: Tranquilo. Se puder marcar como resposta eu agradeço. Mais tarde vou editar com a parte de adicionar o restante do path e um pouco mais de explicações pra ficar mais completo

Comment: Blz. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Pronto amigo, adicionei o path!

Comment: Hum. Ah ta. Vou testar

Answer (score 1):

Para retornar a letra do *drive* em que o sistema está instalado

```
System.getenv("SystemDrive");
```

**`SystemDrive`** é uma variável de ambiente do Windows, você pode capturar o valor de qualquer uma das variáveis.